# Arrow functions in object literal vs arrow functions in class generated objects

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

```
const objectLiteral = {
  x: 5,
  getX: () => {
      console.log(`The value of x is ${this.x}`); 
  }
} 
x.getX(); // The value of x is undefined
```

Why `this` doesn't bind to the getX method when I use an object literal? Doesn't the arrow function get their `this` from the parent scope? In this case the objectLiteral. But it does when I use class generated object.

```
class classObject {
  x = 5;
  getX = () => {
      console.log(`The value of x is ${this.x}`);
  }

  const classObjectInstance = new classObject();
  classObjectInstance.getX(); // The value of x is 5
}
```

Comment: Class fields are syntactic sugar for setting a property in the constructor, i.e. `constructor() { this.getX = () => ...; }`, where `this` refers to the new instance. That's not the case of object literals. The property values are evaluated before the object even exists.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you